# Why is chorizo spice-mix rarely sold in stores?

Tags: spices, mexican-cuisine, chorizo

I'm not much of a cook, but I do enjoy anything made with chorizo.

I've looked far and wide for pre-made chorizo spice-mix in grocery stores, international food stores, etc., but I've never found it.

Yet, chorizo **sausage is widely available** at grocery stores, restaurants, butcher shops and even convenience stores.

The closest thing I've found to pre-made chorizo spice is a backcountry mix on [Amazon.ca](https://www.amazon.ca/LEM-Products-9010-Backwoods-Seasoning/dp/B009SJADD8/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1547324226&sr=8-7&keywords=chorizo).

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a known reason why chorizo spice wouldn't be sold in stores? For example, is it just as easy to make it as it would be to buy it?

Comment: Basically chorizo is made with meat, bacon, paprika and garlic. Add black pepper for spicy chorizo.

Comment: I've only gotten it once as a wet blend to mix into ground pork.  Unfortunately, it through kickstarter for someone starting up a business, and it looks like they closed up shop ( https://www.facebook.com/MunecaMexicanafood ).  It's a shame, it was really good.

Comment: You can add a little Arbol if your paprika is weak, as it often is here in the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple brands of chorizo spice mix available commercially: [Spice House](https://www.thespicehouse.com/chorizo-mexican-sausage-seasoning-blend?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&dst=google.cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwY3Ho6rp3wIVCeDICh3-GghCEAQYASABEgJY__D_BwE), [Savory Spice](https://www.savoryspiceshop.com/chorizo-sausage-spice?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwY3Ho6rp3wIVCeDICh3-GghCEAQYAiABEgIktvD_BwE), [sausage maker supply](https://www.meatprocessingproducts.com/91400.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwY3Ho6rp3wIVCeDICh3-GghCEAQYAyABEgI6RvD_BwE), etc.  Google a little.

Further, if you go to a grocery store with a good selection of Mexican food, you'll probably find some mixes there from Latin suppliers who don't have web sites.  Maybe not, though; all of those spices are standard staples for Mexican cooks, so they wouldn't see the need for a mix.

My recommendation, though, is that you make your own spice mix so that you can balance out the heat/garlic/sweet spices the way you like it.

Answer (score 2):

Local availability is going to depend on, well... where you are located. But @fuzzychef has a point, you can make your own. Famous Chef Emeril Lagasse offers a [Chorizo Seasoning Recipe](https://emerils.com/126059/chorizo-seasoning). I'm not sure how long it would take you to use up 1/2 Cup of the mix... you might consider using garlic powder instead of the chopped garlic (to prolong shelf life).